# Changing shapefile longitude from -180-180 to 0-360 in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r

I have a world shapefile. I am reading the shapefile using readOGR() function from rgdal package. The shapefile which I have has Greenwich as the prime meridian. I got the world shapefile from this [link](https://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip).

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

Shapefile <- readOGR("Directory of Shapefile")
```

The CRS of this shapefile is given below.

```
> crs(Shapefile)
  CRS Arguments:
   +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

I have to convert this shapefile into a similar world shapefile as shown below.
The longitudes of output shapefile should range from 0 to 359 where the latitude remains the same.
[image]

Is there some way to do this thing in R?

My output shapefile should look something like as shown as above.

Comment: If you wish to also ask about how to do this in ArcGIS Desktop then please do that in a separate question rather than by seeking two sets of answers within a single question. I edited ArcGIS Desktop out of your question for that reason.